# Understanding how to read output voltage of a current transformer sensor

Tags: sensor

I am try to understand how to read data from current transformer circuit. As reference  i am reading on this 2 articles: [Article1](http://myelectronichome.altervista.org/joomla/en/excessive-current-detector-with-sct-013-020-or-sct-013-030.html) and [Article2](https://scidle.com/how-to-use-non-invasive-ac-current-sensors-with-arduino/). I do not have easy access to oscilloscope which make it a bit harder for me to visualize.

Here is the circuit that Article one and two uses. (PS i am assuming the version where the burden resistor is built in to the sensor already)

[image]

What is the purpose of the Equal value resistor voltage divider and the capacitor? How would i compute the resistor and capacitor value?

what would be the reading if probes are directly connected to JACK A and B

Answer (score 0):

The resistor divider is used for making a reference voltage. When no voltage difference is present between A and B, you get half of Vcc on the analog pin - say 1.65V. When the voltage difference A-B is positive you get more than 1.65V on analog pin, meanwhile when voltage A-B is negative you get less than 1.65V.

Between A and B you have to connect a burden resistor, then a CT.

> What is the purpose of the Equal value resistor voltage divider and
>   the capacitor? How would i compute the resistor and capacitor value?

Leave it the same. If it works for others, it will work for you, also.

> what would be the reading if probes are directly connected to JACK A
>   and B

Don't quite understand this question.

Comment: What would happen if i directly read the analog pin on Jack A and connect Jack B to ground?